# Best way of Form Validation in Windows Store App

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am developing Windows Store Application(C# + XAML), in which I am developing user registration form. I want to validate textbox fields that whether they have valid text or not. What is the best way of textbox validation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate all the textboxes at once then you should validate on save button click or any other event. If any of textbox is depend on another then you should validate in `LostFocus` event.

Comment: I think there's no another way because different textbox will have different validation logic so you can create common `LostFocus` event and use switch case to identify particular textbox and do validation.

Comment: I want controls like Range Validator as in asp.net.

Comment: You can use regular expression for that. Just Google it.